# Ruby Sinatra - Authenticate user against local user database (linux / mac)

Tags: ruby, http, authentication, sinatra

Is it possible to authenticate user against the local user database on linux/mac?
I would like to create users locally on linux and then force authentication using sinatra or any other suggested ruby gem (no rails knowledge :()

I don't have any database and my app is so simple it should look like this:

```
require 'sinatra'

use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |username, password|
  [username, password] == ['admin', 'admin']
end

get '/' do
  "You're welcome"
end
```

Comment: Hi Marko! Welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't think that you've provided enough information in the question. For quidelines on how to ask a better question look at this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We also like to see some attempt to answer your question youself, showing some research. Please just do some googling to specify your question further. We also do not include a signature like "Regards" so please edit that out.

Comment: Specifically please include what type of database and if your server is run locally or not.

Comment: Thank you @thesecretmaster for your guidelines.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check if a user has an account on the computer running the ruby code?

Comment: Yes. I want to perform check/auth against local users in linux or mac (i'm not having any type of database).

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I would like to create two user roles in Ruby, anonymous and admins. Also, I would like to simplify management of users by querying local users in linux and if they exist and they're authenticated to show some protected info using Sinatra. Please let me know if you need detailed explanation but that's pretty much it.

Comment: No, why do you need to use the local users?

Comment: To simplify administration. If someone add local user in Linux, I don't need to create user in Ruby database.

Comment: I don't know of any way to access the local users, and if there was a way it would be insecure because you would have to access the passwords. In 5 hours or so I'll post an answer for using a database. If anyone else knows a way to check against local users, they can post that

Comment: I need something like Windows Authentication in IIS on Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use a database. If you end up going that route here is how you would do it:

Add to your gemfile `gem 'sqlite'` and `gem 'sinatra-activerecord'`
Run the command `bundle exec rake db:create_migration NAME=setup_users_table`. This will create a `db` directory containing `migrations/<random numbers>_setup_users_table.rb`. In that file, add code inside the `change` function.
To create a Users table with a username and password field add the following code:

```
create_table :users do |i|
    i.string :username
    i.string :password
end
```

Now run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. If that has succeded then you have a working database.
To access it you need to add to your app file the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Now you're good to go!

To create a user:

```
User.create(username:<whatever>,password:<whatever>)
```